# How do I delete a specific HTML <table> with Perl?

Tags: html, perl, html-table, html-parsing

I need to delete certain tables based on the contents of the table. I parsed the HTML using [`HTML::Tree`](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTree) to build an HTML tree.

I used `replace_with_content` to delete the table but that only removes the table tag and leaves the contents of the table.

Please note that the tables are nested.

```
my $content = get($url);

my $tree = HTML::Tree->new();
$tree->parse($content);

my (@table_tags) = $tree->look_down( '_tag' , 'table' );
my $string = $table_tags[0]->as_HTML;

my $tree2 = HTML::Tree->new();
$tree2->parse($string);

my (@table_tags2) = $tree2->look_down( '_tag' , 'table' );
$table_tags2[3]->replace_with_content();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using [delete](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aElement#delete) instead of `replace_with_content`?

Answer (score 1):

To remove a table you want simply

```
$table->delete;
```

I am not sure if you are having problems selecting the tables to delete, but how you do it depends on what the criteria are. The methods in [`HTML::Element`](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) will allow you to navigate the tree and test parts of it, or you could add conditions to your call to `look_down`